# Как правильно использовать jquery в html

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Насколько я знаю, скрипты принято подключать внизу страницы, чтобы ускорить прогрузку основного конетента. Поэтому jquery на странице я хочу подключить как можно ниже.

Файл common.js со всякими функциями подключен еще ниже, все в нем обернуто в $(document).ready. Все хорошо.

Но вот возникла необходимость написать ajax-запрос прямо в html, а не в common.js. Соответственно, в момент, когда браузер встречает скрипт, jquery еще не подключен, ничего не работает. В $(document).ready тоже не обернешь, ведь это тоже jquery.

Как принято решать такую проблему? Очевидный выход - перенести подключение jquery в шапку, но есть ли другие нормальные варианты?

Comment: Скрипты во внешних файлах как раз лучше ставить в начале страницы. они грузятся параллельно основной странице и не замедляют загрузку. И чем раньше они будут встречены, тем раньше они загрузятся сами, а значит раньше произойдет полная готовность страницы к работе

Comment: Ну так а как быть в итоге с проблемой, когда код jquery встречается раньше, чем подключен или загружен jquery? Насколько я понимаю, даже если грузить асинхронно в верхней части страницы, браузер раньше встретит код, написанный в html и не сможет его понять, потому что jquery еще не загрузится.

Comment: пользуйтесь нативными событиями, привлекать jquery для навешивания событий не обязательно. `window.addEventListener('load', ...` например

Comment: `$(document).ready(function(){...});`→ аналог на JS будет `(function(){ ... })();` в данном случае JS даже удобнее использовать)

Comment: @OPTIMUSPRIME привиденные вами примеры не эквивалетнты.